# Difference between Sequential and Weak Sequential Equilbria

Tags: game-theory, economics, nash-equilibrium

This is in reference to the Game theoretic concepts as Nash equilibrium refinements. Sequential equilibrium are often defined as satisfying two conditions: consistency and sequential rationality. Whereas Weak Sequential Equilibria (sometimes referred to as Weak Perfect Bayesian) also necessitates sequential rationality, but has a weaker consistency requirement,which is my main source of confusion. Moreover, SE and WSE(WPBE) are often coincide as sets of solutions which really only adds to the frustration of trying to differentiate these almost identical concepts. My main question is, how would I go about checking the consistency requirement for a given extensive form game?

Comment: Cross-post? http://economics.stackexchange.com/q/9834/42

Comment: Yes, I made that question initially before I had signed in, but mathstackexchange apparently didn't recognize it as belonging to me?
Either way, thank you for linking it! It's a great answer although I can't upvote it or close the question because it doesn't recognize me as the asker.

Comment: You can follow the information here (http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts, or http://economics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to request the two accounts be merged.